# Django / WSGI blank page

Tags: django, apache, wsgi

I am trying to get Django to work together with Apache using WSGI. The problem is that it simply returns an empty page (200 OK or 203 not modified).

I can't find any error upon restarting or when accessing the page in either error.log or django-error.log. There is an entry in django-access.log though.

```
WSGIPythonPath /web/django/dtest/
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /web/django
    ServerName django.markv.nl
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks Includes
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    WSGIScriptAlias /wsgi-scripts/ /web/django/dtest/dtest/wsgi.py
    LogLevel info
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/django-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/django-access.log common
</VirtualHost>
```

- I tried using the `manage.py runserver`, in which case it works fine, so it's really an apache/wsgi problem.
- I tried disabling mod_php5 with no result (except that PHP stopped working).

Any clues what the problem is or where I can find an error? It's probably something trivial but I fail to find it...

Comment: even i had such a problem once it was because of static files. 
does your project have static files ?? if so you'll have to see how to [deploy static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/static-files/deployment/).

Comment: Not that it is going to be the cause of your issue, it is not usual to have a trailing slash on the URL mount point for a sub URL. That is, use '/wsgi-scripts' and not '/wsgi-scripts/'. Also, where is Apache even being allowed to access files in /web/django/dtest/dtest? Suggests that VirtualHost isn't even being used. Go back and read the Django docs on mod_wsgi deployment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're serving your application at `/wsgi-scripts/`, which seems an odd thing to do, so you'll need to go to that URL to see it.

Note that you absolutely certainly do not want to set your DocumentRoot to the location of your Django files, although this is not the source of your problem.

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question and thanks for the answer and hint!